# Query PFObject while subquerying one of its attribute (array)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a "Book" class containing general informations like author, pages number, released date and so on. This class also contains an array "localizations" which contains pointers to multiple objects of a "BookLocalization" class.

Each "BookLocalization" object has a "langageCode" to identify its langage (en, de, fr, es, ...) and other other localized informations like "plot".

I would like to query the "Book" class while only fetching a particular langage ("langageCode") for its "localizations", so I do not get an array with all the "localizations" for each "Book" I fetch.

Is it possible in one request ? Such request would really lighten my requests. Imagine if I support 50 langages or more...

I really appreciate any help !

UPDATE : Here is what I tried with no success

```
PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"BookLocalization"];
[innerQuery whereKey:@"langageCode" equalTo:@"de"];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Book"];
[query whereKey:@"localizations" matchesQuery:innerQuery];
[query whereKey:@"title" equalTo:@"Foundation"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    PFObject *firstObject = (PFObject*)objects.firstObject;
    NSLog(@"%@", firstObject[@"localizations"]);
}];
```

And what I get :

```
(
    "<BookLocalization: 0x600000121360, objectId: 87NFuvWcCa, localId: (null)> {\n}",
    "<BookLocalization: 0x600000120460, objectId: SzORHjuI0y, localId: (null)> {\n}",
    "<BookLocalization: 0x6000001212c0, objectId: qzq7FGDTtI, localId: (null)> {\n}",
    "<BookLocalization: 0x600000120640, objectId: jc04H6L3uf, localId: (null)> {\n}"
)
```

I am still getting all the localizations for this book, not only "de" as I would in this case. Any idea ? Maybe I should design it in an other way ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to form an `innerQuery` on BookLocalization with `whereKey:@"languageCode" equalTo:@"de"`, say, for German.

But you won't run that inner query explicitly.  Instead, pass it as a parameter to a query on Book, `whereKey:@"localizations" matchesQuery:innerQuery`.  Running this query on Book will get the job done.

(Of course, there are really two queries being run here, but the innerQuery is run by parse.com, so it's fair to think of that as one request from the client's perspective)

Comment: I tried your solution and updated my original post, still not working :(